# Run .Exe inside Application

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-machine, virtualization

I need to create an application to run programs. It should work as VmWare or VirtualBox, but to run other programs and not an operating system. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Are you asking for `Process.Start()`?

Comment: Maybe sandboxing an application is what you ask for.

Comment: @SLaks Process.Start only will cause the process to start and is not what I need. No sense why?

Comment: @modosansreves sandboxing, i go to google.

Comment: You can't really do proper sandboxing without a full VM.

Comment: Yes I have a suggestion. Start researching how to code a sandbox application and how to secure it then come back when you have a question following SO guidelines related to that task.

Comment: any particular reason that you do not use Vmware or Virtualbox?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do can't be accomplished in a simple way.

You still need a virtual machine of some sort, or an application container. I know that Microsoft is working on a Windows application container (like Docker) but I don't believe it is available yet.